# HTML no-wrap conflicting with Divs text wrapping

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to use the `white-space: nowrap` in CSS to allow scrolling on overflow.

However, this prevents the `innerHTML` inside the *divs* to wrap.

If I remove the `white-space: nowrap`, the `innerHTML` works as it should but the *divs* don't scroll, instead they go onto new line.

### With no-wrap:

[image]

### Without no-wrap:

[image]

Comment: You want horizontal scroll? if you want that, you need to use `overflow-x:auto` and not `none`. also, the title of the question does not describe what you actually want / the issue iteself

Comment: Yes, I have overflow-x: scroll

Comment: so what is the problem? you can set `min-width` on the `div`s and it will create a scroll eventually if there's enough to go out of the viewport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

in the outer div and in each inner div:

```
white-space: normal;
```

for example:

```
.outer-div{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.outer-div>div{
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of a few `div` elements, with a horizontal scroll when they overflow their parent node, which is a `section` in this demo.

In the below demo, I thought it best to use `flexbox`, which gives some nice benefits.

```css
section{  
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 150px;
}

div{  
  flex: 400px;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>some very very long text which should probably break because it is very long.</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Right but the problem is, once I get the scroll to work, the innerhtml of the divs like "MoreJob2 Aribazerto", stays on one line. I want that to wrap inside the div constraint. But the white-space no-wrap prevents that. Please look at the second picture to see what I'm referring to

Comment: it's just a matter of inheritance. if that is so, then the obvious thing to do it to give a more specific style to the div themselves. i'm fixing my example